# Examples of custom BIRT report items other than in BIRT Controls

Tags: birt

When looking for examples of custom BIRT report items, there are a few versions of RotatedText/RotatedLabel around, and DotBar (only in [BIRT Controls Library](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/birt-controls-lib/)). Any others?